# Objective C how to re add the deleted items in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my code, three text fields are there for picker views. For example in the first text field, the user selects A+ blood group, in the second text field we don't want to display A+ blood group. Remaining items need to display. Text field 3 also same. For example, in text field 2 the user selects B+ blood group, in text field 3 B+ and A+ blood group needs to remove in array list. For example the user again selects the first text field and reselects another blood group like A- ve group re add the A+ blood group in array list. The same thing in text field2 and text field3. I already completed the one task, i.e removing items from array. The pending task is re adding the items in array.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A+",@"A-",@"B+",@"B-",@"O+",@"O-", nil];
    bloodGroup = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, logoImg.frame.origin.y+logoImg.frame.size.height+45, screenWidth-20, 50)];
    bloodGroup.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    bloodGroup.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    bloodGroup.placeholder = @"Please Select Your Option";
    bloodGroup.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:bloodGroup];

    txtField1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, ansField1.frame.origin.y+ansField1.frame.size.height+45, screenWidth-20, 50)];
    txtField1.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    txtField1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    txtField1.placeholder = @"Please Select Your Option";
    txtField1.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:txtField1];

    txtField2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, ansField2.frame.origin.y+ansField2.frame.size.height+45, screenWidth-20, 50)];
    txtField2.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    txtField2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    txtField2.placeholder = @"Please Select Your Option";
    txtField2.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:txtField2];

    myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    [myPickerView setDataSource: self];
    [myPickerView setDelegate: self];
    myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    bloodGroup.inputView = myPickerView;
    bloodGroup.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;

    // txtField1
    txtField1.inputView = myPickerView;
    txtField1.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;
    txtField2.inputView = myPickerView;
    txtField2.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    if (isBloodGroupFieldSelected) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (!isBloodGroupFieldSelected) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (!isGenderGroupFieldSelected) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (isBloodGroupFieldSelected) {
        return [dataArray count];
    }
    else if (!isBloodGroupFieldSelected) {
        return [dataArray count];
    }
    else if (!isGenderGroupFieldSelected) {
        return [dataArray count];
    }

    return 0;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (isBloodGroupFieldSelected) {
        return dataArray[row];
    }
    else if ((!isBloodGroupFieldSelected) && (isGenderGroupFieldSelected)) {
        return dataArray[row];
    }
    else if (!isGenderGroupFieldSelected) {
        return dataArray[row];
    }

    return 0;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (isBloodGroupFieldSelected) {
        bloodGroup.text = dataArray[row];
    }
    else if ((!isBloodGroupFieldSelected) && (isGenderGroupFieldSelected)) {
        txtField1.text = dataArray[row];
    }
    else if (!isGenderGroupFieldSelected) {
        txtField2.text= dataArray[row];
    }
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == bloodGroup) {
        isBloodGroupFieldSelected = YES;
    }
    else if (textField == txtField1) {
        isBloodGroupFieldSelected = NO;
        isGenderGroupFieldSelected = YES;
    }
    else if (textField == txtField2) {
        isGenderGroupFieldSelected = NO;
        isBloodGroupFieldSelected = NO;
    }

    [myPickerView reloadAllComponents];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [myPickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
}

- (void)done:(id)sender {
    [myPickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES]; // On 27/04/2020
    [bloodGroup resignFirstResponder];
    [txtField1 resignFirstResponder];
    [txtField2 resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: You need four arrays. One is the complete list of options. The other three are the options available in each picker. When a choice is made in one picker you need to update the other two arrays by copying the original, complete list and skipping the options that have been selected in a picker.

Comment: @Paulw11 can you please share me the sample code

Comment: @iosdeveloper It helps if you try and write it yourself and then come back with specific questions rather than just asking for the solution in code.